# RequireJS + Lodash + IE8 = not loading lodash as a module

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, requirejs, lodash

I'm dealing with weird situation. I'm loading lodash as a AMD module with requirejs and everything works perfect... except IE8 and below. I saw that loadsh file is actualy loaded in the IE debug tool > network... but when I console.log it out it gives me 'undefined'. I'm stuck. Also... there are no errors in the debug console.

Any thoguts, tips ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis of [this documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#ieloadfail), you should set `enforceDefine` to true in your RequireJS configuration and make sure that all shims have a proper `exports` value. A proper `exports` value is one which contains a symbol which is defined *only* by the module being shimmed.