# RequireJS shim issues with IE8 and less

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, internet-explorer-8, requirejs, amd

I'm having a hard time here, I'm trying to load non-AMD modules jquery / lodash / underscore before any of my AMD modules will be loaded. I know that I should use 'shim' and I do. Evertyghing seems to work in every browser except IE8 and less. Is there some kind of workaround for IE7/8 ?

I've took a look at 'use' plugin / 'order' plugin and wrapping global variables into AMD modules (http://tbranyen.com/post/amdrequirejs-shim-plugin-for-loading-incompatible-javascript). Everything faild. Any ideas of how should it be done?

**EDIT**

```
require.config({
use: {
    backbone: {
        deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
        attach: "Backbone"
    },

    underscore: {
        attach: "_"
    },

    jquery : {
        attach: 'jquery'
    }
},
paths: {
    'underscore': 'lodash-1.3.1.min',
    'backbone': 'backbone-1.0.0.min',
    'jquery': 'jquery-1.10.2.min',
}
});

require([
'use',
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'app',
], function($) {
'use strict';
});
```

'use' is the use.js plugin. I've also used 'shim' before.

**EDIT 2**

```
shim: {
    'app': {
        deps: ['backbone']
    },
    'backbone': {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    'underscore': {
        exports: '_'
    },
    'jquery' : {
        exports: 'jquery'
    },
},
```

my shim config. REQUIREJS VERSION IS 2.1.10.

**Edit 3:**

```
require.config({
paths: {
    'underscore': '//cdn.vgc.no/js/libs/lodash/lodash-1.3.1.min',
    'backbone': '//cdn.vgc.no/js/libs/backbone/backbone-1.0.0.min',
    'jquery': '//cdn.vgc.no/js/libs/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min'
},
enforceDefine : true
});

require([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone'
], function($, _, Backbone) {
'use strict';

console.log($);
console.log(_);
console.log(Backbone);
})
```

does this should work under IE8 ?

Comment: Hmm... how come you don't have `enforceDefine` and `exports` set as I suggested in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928999/requirejs-lodash-ie8-not-loading-lodash-as-a-module)? If it is because you use `use`, then don't use `use`. There's nothing in your question that suggests to me you should be using `use`. Did I miss something?

Comment: cause 'enforceDefine' just gives U an information what's wrong, and I know what is it... Backbone and the rest are not AMD. So In my mind shim is not working with IE7/8 - is that right ?

Comment: The thing is... does SHIM work under IE8 and less? If not... is there a workaround for it?

Comment: Shims should be working even in IE7 and IE8. However, it is possible to to write a shim that won't work correctly. The config in your question should show us how you use the `shim` configuration. Also, make sure you are using RequireJS 2.x because `shim` does not exist in the 1.x series. (It happened that we've had questions asked here on SO where the problem was the the user used an old version of RequireJS.)

Comment: ok, please take a look above.

Comment: Lodash & Backbone are amd compliant too, so remove the `exports`.

Comment: @asgoth Ah, when a module is compliant, then the *whole shim* config for that module should be removed, not just `exports`. Good catch with the lodash thing. I was thrown off by `underscore` (which AFAIK needs a shim). And I did not realize Backbone has moved to support AMD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shim for `jquery` is superfluous.

Also, if `app` is an actual RequireJS module, you do not need a shim for it. The `define` call for `app` should be `define(['backbone'], function (Backbone) {...`.

Asgoth pointed out that lodash and Backbone are AMD-compliant so you should not have a shim for `underscore` or `Backbone`. You use lodash for `underscore`. Lodash has not needed a shim in a while (maybe ever). `Backbone` used to need a shim but it now has support for AMD-style loaders.

So at the moment, none of the shims in your configuration seem necessary. You should still use `enforceDefine`.

In case this was the source of confusion, let me clarify that the basic rule for using shims is this: if a module uses `define` to define itself, then it must not have a shim; if a module does not use `define`, then it must have a shim. The documentation that talks about using `enforceDefine` and making sure that all shims have `exports` set does not change this rule. What it is saying is that *if* a shim is required (according to the rule above), *then* this shim should have an `exports` field.

**Edit:** I'm able to get it to load in IE8 with the following code. You'll see a shim for Backbone there, despite my earlier comments. Why? Because you are using Backbone 1.0.0 which does not have AMD support. The latest version, Backbone 1.1.2, has support for AMD. So if you were to upgrade to this version, you would not need the shim. (This code prefixes the CDN paths with `http:` but I do not believe it is a factor in your problem. It's just that I first loaded the test HTML from my local filesystem and to do this, the `http:` prefix was required.)

```
  require.config({
      paths: {
          'underscore': 'http://cdn.vgc.no/js/libs/lodash/lodash-1.3.1.min',
          'backbone': 'http://cdn.vgc.no/js/libs/backbone/backbone-1.0.0.min',
          'jquery': 'http://cdn.vgc.no/js/libs/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min'
      },
      shim: {
          backbone: {
              deps: ["jquery", "underscore"],
              exports: "Backbone"
          }
      },
      enforceDefine : true
  });

  require([
      'jquery',
      'underscore',
      'backbone'
  ], function($, _, Backbone) {
      'use strict';

      console.log($);
      console.log(_);
      console.log(Backbone);
  });
```

Here's a screenshot of the console output in IE8:

[image: Screenshot in SauceLab]

Comment: jquery shouldn't be there at all (in the `shim`section). It is amd compliant.

Comment: @OskarSzura "Nothing" as in, no error message whatsoever? I've edited my answer with another possible problem. `app` looks to me like a RequireJS module, so...

Comment: sorry, but I have still the same issue. checkout on the Edit3 - should this work under IE8 ? Because it doesn't... What console logs are displaying is 3x undefined.